# reorder/standardize and create rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I have been looking for a solution to an existing dataframe I have been given. I have a set of variables, each of which contains some of other subcategories. Assume it looks something like this:

```
Michael Physics 1 2
Michael Math 2 4
Michael Science 3 4
Michael PE 2 1
James Art 0 9
James PE 1 2
James Physics -1 2
James Science 1 2
Simon PE 1 2
Simon Art 1 3
Simon Music 1 4
Simon Science 1 4
```

Notably, the second column has a "standard" set of variables, so that each student shares most but not necessarily all of the variables, and the ordering of these variables is scrambled. My issue is then that I want to convert this dataframe to a "standard format". That is I want each of the students to have ALL of the variables and in the same order. So if I define a list of all the subjects: say Physics, Math, Science, Art, PE, Music. I would like for there to be 18 rows in my modified dataframe(6 for each student, with the ordering defined for the subject). If the student and subject are contained in the original dataset, the row should have the data from the row, and if the student and subject doesnt exist in the original dataframe, then the other datacolumns would just be NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update on OP's comment:

To keep the original order you could factor `Student` and define level:

```
df <-  df %>% 
  mutate(Student = factor(Student, levels = c("Michael", "James", "Simon")))

df1 <- df %>%  
  expand(Student, Course)

df %>% 
  right_join(df1) %>% 
  arrange(Student, Course)
```

Output:

```
   Student Course     V1    V2
   <fct>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Michael Art        NA    NA
 2 Michael Math        2     4
 3 Michael Music      NA    NA
 4 Michael PE          2     1
 5 Michael Physics     1     2
 6 Michael Science     3     4
 7 James   Art         0     9
 8 James   Math       NA    NA
 9 James   Music      NA    NA
10 James   PE          1     2
11 James   Physics    -1     2
12 James   Science     1     2
13 Simon   Art         1     3
14 Simon   Math       NA    NA
15 Simon   Music       1     4
16 Simon   PE          1     2
17 Simon   Physics    NA    NA
18 Simon   Science     1     4
```

We could combine `expand` and `right_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  expand(Student, Course)

df %>% 
  right_join(df1) %>% 
  arrange(Student, Course)
```

Output:

```
   Student Course     V1    V2
   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 James   Art         0     9
 2 James   Math       NA    NA
 3 James   Music      NA    NA
 4 James   PE          1     2
 5 James   Physics    -1     2
 6 James   Science     1     2
 7 Michael Art        NA    NA
 8 Michael Math        2     4
 9 Michael Music      NA    NA
10 Michael PE          2     1
11 Michael Physics     1     2
12 Michael Science     3     4
13 Simon   Art         1     3
14 Simon   Math       NA    NA
15 Simon   Music       1     4
16 Simon   PE          1     2
17 Simon   Physics    NA    NA
18 Simon   Science     1     4
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. How would I preserve the original ordering of the students as well?(Though this is not really part of the original question)

Answer (score 1):

In the below, we repeatedly use `pivot_` to get the desired result. The output is sorted by student name and subject.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_delim("Michael Physics 1 2
Michael Math 2 4
Michael Science 3 4
Michael PE 2 1
James Art 0 9
James PE 1 2
James Physics -1 2
James Science 1 2
Simon PE 1 2
Simon Art 1 3
Simon Music 1 4
Simon Science 1 4", delim = " ", col_names = c("student", "subject", "v1", "v2"))

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "subject", values_from = c("v1", "v2")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("v"), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("var", "subject"), sep = "_") %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>% 
  arrange(student, subject)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#>    student subject    v1    v2
#>    <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 James   Art         0     9
#>  2 James   Math       NA    NA
#>  3 James   Music      NA    NA
#>  4 James   PE          1     2
#>  5 James   Physics    -1     2
#>  6 James   Science     1     2
#>  7 Michael Art        NA    NA
#>  8 Michael Math        2     4
#>  9 Michael Music      NA    NA
#> 10 Michael PE          2     1
#> 11 Michael Physics     1     2
#> 12 Michael Science     3     4
#> 13 Simon   Art         1     3
#> 14 Simon   Math       NA    NA
#> 15 Simon   Music       1     4
#> 16 Simon   PE          1     2
#> 17 Simon   Physics    NA    NA
#> 18 Simon   Science     1     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `complete`. To preserve the original ordering of the data you can save the name of the students in a variable and use `match` and `arrange`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

orignal_order <- unique(df$V1)

df %>% complete(V1, V2) %>% arrange(match(V1, orignal_order))

#   V1      V2         V3    V4
#   <chr>   <chr>   <int> <int>
# 1 Michael Art        NA    NA
# 2 Michael Math        2     4
# 3 Michael Music      NA    NA
# 4 Michael PE          2     1
# 5 Michael Physics     1     2
# 6 Michael Science     3     4
# 7 James   Art         0     9
# 8 James   Math       NA    NA
# 9 James   Music      NA    NA
#10 James   PE          1     2
#11 James   Physics    -1     2
#12 James   Science     1     2
#13 Simon   Art         1     3
#14 Simon   Math       NA    NA
#15 Simon   Music       1     4
#16 Simon   PE          1     2
#17 Simon   Physics    NA    NA
#18 Simon   Science     1     4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Michael", "Michael", "Michael", "Michael", 
"James", "James", "James", "James", "Simon", "Simon", "Simon", 
"Simon"), V2 = c("Physics", "Math", "Science", "PE", "Art", "PE", 
"Physics", "Science", "PE", "Art", "Music", "Science"), V3 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(2L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```